# Using cueritos (Pork Rinds) for ground beef

Tags: substitutions, meat, beef, sausages

Can I use cueritos as my fat to make burger? I usually use pork fat but my butcher was out today so I bought 2 pounds of this delicious stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You want to grind the cueritos with leaner meat to make a higher fat ground meat? There is no reason that wouldn't work. You might find it necessary to remove the very outer skin, but I'd try a small batch without taking that step. The grinding might eliminate any textural problems (or it might not, so try a little bit first).